# react-native-fs ENOENT: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied), open '/storage/emulated/0/Download/ after reinstall

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fs

*Hello everyone*

**Environment :**

- Android 11
- react-native 0.68.5
- react-native-fs 2.20.0

**Need:**

Save files persistent to the application (if I uninstall the application the files need to persist). If I reinstall the application I need to be able to manipulate these files again. I uploaded the files in the download folder with `RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath` so that they are not deleted when the application is uninstalled but the files are public and can be downloaded to another location if needed.

**Error:**

Everything works perfectly until I uninstall and reinstall the application. As soon as I want to manipulate an existing file in my `/storage/emulated/0/Download/AppName/...`

I encounter the following error when I want to move file :

```
Error: ENOENT: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied), open '/storage/emulated/0/Download/AppName/...
```

I encounter the following error when I want to download file :

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/storage/emulated/0/Download
```

Before manipulating a file I make sure I have the :

- PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

My build.gradle :

```
buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0" 
minSdkVersion = 30 
compileSdkVersion = 31 
targetSdkVersion = 31
```

My manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
....
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
...
```

A big thank you to the people who will take their time to help me

To try to solve the problem I added this line in my manifest :

```
android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

and I changed the `minSdkVersion` in my `build.gradle` from 21 to 30.

I have the impression that the rights belonged to the application as if by reinstalling the application it lost its rights.

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell it but this happens to you on Android 11+ devices.

On Android 11+ an app has only access to the files it created itself and media files in public directories.

After reinstall an app is considered a different app.

Use Storage Access Framework ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user pick the files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer indeed it is well with android 11 I modified the post to add it, I will inquire in this direction